# List not populating in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to have a form when I fill it out will populate a ListView, but can't seem to get the list to popluate with any values.

I am using the following to have a bottom navigation:

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> body = [
    AddNewStudent(),
    StudentList(),
  ];
```

In a file that has the form looks like this:

```
class StudentClass {
  String kidFirstName;
  String kidLastName;
  DateTime dateOfBirth;
  int totalAttedance = 0;
  int attedanceAtRank = 0;

  StudentClass(
      {required this.kidFirstName,
      required this.kidLastName,
      required this.dateOfBirth});
}

class AddNewStudent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AddStudentScreen createState() => AddStudentScreen();
}

class AddStudentScreen extends State<AddNewStudent> {
  List<StudentClass> studentList = [];
  void addStudent(StudentClass newStudent) {
    setState(() {
      studentList.add(newStudent);
    });
  }
  
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  kidsFirstNameFormField(),
                  kidLastNameFormField(),
                  kidDateofBirth(),
                  submitButton(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )));
  }
Widget submitButton() {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Text('Create New Student Profile'),
      onPressed: () {
        if (formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
          formKey.currentState?.save();
          StudentClass newStudent = StudentClass(
            kidFirstName: kidFirstName,
            kidLastName: kidLastName,
            dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth,
          );
          addStudent(newStudent);
          formKey.currentState?.reset();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

The listview builder is in its own file:

```
class StudentList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<StudentClass> studentList = [];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Student List'),
      ),
      body: StudentListState(
        studentList: studentList,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StudentListState extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<StudentClass> studentList;
  StudentListState({required this.studentList});
  @override
  _StudentListState createState() => _StudentListState();
}

class _StudentListState extends State<StudentListState> {
  void addStudent(StudentClass student) {
    setState(() {
      widget.studentList.add(student);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.studentList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(widget.studentList[index].kidFirstName),
              subtitle: Text(widget.studentList[index].kidLastName),
              trailing: Text(widget.studentList[index].dateOfBirth.toString()),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

I am pretty stuck on figuring out how to pass the information over to the list to populate. I have gotten it to build with no errors but somehow I know I am not passing it correctly. I know I might have an extra list in here.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the `studentList` of the `AddStudentScreen` widget. And in the `ListView` you are rendering the `studentList` from `StudentList` widget which is a different variable and is always empty.

Also, you are initialising `studentList` inside the `build` function which means that on every `setState()` `studentList` will be initialised to an empty list.

Seems like you want to use the same data in multiple widgets. In such cases consider using a state manager.

For you scenario, I'd recommend you use [stream_mixin](https://pub.dev/packages/stream_mixin).

Example:

- Create student service using `StoreService` from `stream_mixin` package.

```dart
class StudentModel extends BaseModel { // NOTICE THIS
  String kidFirstName;
  String kidLastName;
  DateTime dateOfBirth;
  int totalAttedance = 0;
  int attedanceAtRank = 0;

  StudentModel({
    required this.kidFirstName,
    required this.kidLastName,
    required this.dateOfBirth,
    required String id,
  }) : super(id: id);
}

class StudentService extends StoreService<StudentModel> { // NOTICE THIS
  StudentService._();
  static StudentService store = StudentService._(); // Just creating a singleton for StudentService.
}
```

- To add student data in the store (note, this can be done anywhere in the app):

```dart
const student = new StudentModel(
  // add student data here
)
StudentService.store.add(student);
```

- Render this list of students

```dart
StreamBuilder<StudentModel>(
  stream: StudentService.store.onChange,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data == null) {
      return Text("No student added yet.");
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: StudentService.store.values.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        const student = StudentService.store.values[index];
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(student.kidFirstName),
          subtitle: Text(student.kidLastName),
          trailing: Text(student.dateOfBirth.toString()),
        );
      },
    )
  },
)
```

Now, every time you add student data using `StudentService.store.add()`, it will emit an event which your `SteamBuilder` with `stream: StudentService.store.onChange` is listening and will update the UI to show the updated list.

This will also eliminate the necessity of `StatefulWidget`. Which means you can use only `StatelessWidget` unless otherwise you require `StatefulWidget` for something else.

Comment: Thanks, will look into using StreamBuilder as it might be useful as the app develops further. In the short term, the list I am building and trying to populate will include a check-in button that will increase the int, an additional button to promote belt rank when an int = x, and reset int to 0. Mid-term is to have an additional list populate with attendance on a given day and a profile page. Would StreamBuilder still be useful?